# Dynamic DTO at the moment of executing an http request in Nest.js

Tags: nestjs

There are several DTO that need to be used dynamically based on the http parameter that comes in the request. For example POST /api/tasks?dto_name=dto_1, you need to substitute the required DTO (dto_1) into the controller, taking into account its validation. Is there a way to do this in Nest.js?

I tried to implement via generics, I can't pass the parameter from http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, by implementing the validation pipe yourself.

This is a simple pipe that does what you want:

```js
class Dto1 {
  @IsNumber()
  n: number;
}

class Dto2 {
  @IsBoolean()
  b: boolean;
}

const DTO_DICT = {
  dto_1: Dto1,
  dto_2: Dto2,
};

/* A type alias to dynamically get a union of all classes from the dictionary */
export type DtosUnion = InstanceType<ValuesOf<typeof DTO_DICT>>;

const mappedPipe = async (
  payload: Record<string, any>,
  dtoKey: keyof typeof DTO_DICT,
  validationPipeOptions: ValidationPipeOptions = { transformOptions: undefined }, // You might want to pass global pipe options or override transform behavior
): Promise<DtosUnion> => {
  /* Validate payload, make sure it exists in your DTO dictionary */
  if (!payload) throw new BadRequestException(`Payload is not an object`);
  const constructor = DTO_DICT[dtoKey];
  if (!constructor) throw new BadRequestException(`Dto doesn't exists: ${dtoKey}`);

  /* Use the constructor that you found to instantiate the relevant Dto */
  const transformed = plainToInstance<any, any>(
    constructor,
    payload,
    validationPipeOptions.transformOptions,
  );

  /* Run the validations */
  const validation = await validate(transformed);
  if (!validation.length) return transformed;

  /* This is what Nest does out of the box behind the scenes when validation fails */
  const validationPipe = new ValidationPipe(validationPipeOptions);
  const exceptionFactory = validationPipe.createExceptionFactory();
  const exception = exceptionFactory(validation);
  throw exception;
};
```

This is how it's used:

```js
@Post()
async create(@Body() dto: DtosUnion, @Query('dto_name') dtoName: string): Promise<any> {
  const validatedDto = mappedPipe(dto, dtoName);

  /* Do what you need with the `validatedDto` */
  /* ... */
}
```

`validatedDto` is still of type `DtosUnion`, since after the pipe it can be any of the DTOs(or it can fail validation and throw). If you'll print `validatedDto` in runtime - you'll get the specific DTO you expect.

Do note that if the provided DTO name matches a DTO that has loose validation, it might pass validation for payloads that shouldn't have been passing.

Comment: This is a very good option. At first glance, this is what I need. Thank you very much. I will try it soon and post my result.

Comment: Feel free to ask more questions if you need and mark the answer as accepted if it helped :)